# I have a Topic with 0 leader and 0 isr: UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION

Tags: apache-kafka

I tried to create some messages in my Topic `test_partitions_41` but I got this error:

```
[2019-02-07 14:53:17,484] WARN [Producer clientId=perfs-0e930f51-38a1-5baa-8fcf-f2b1033a73f0] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 738756 : {test_partitions_41=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

when I checked the topic, I found that partitions have neither Leader nor isr:

```
Topic:test_partitions_41        PartitionCount:4        ReplicationFactor:4     Configs:
        Topic: test_partitions_41       Partition: 0    Leader: none    Replicas: 4,1,2,3       Isr:
        Topic: test_partitions_41       Partition: 1    Leader: none    Replicas: 1,2,3,4       Isr:
        Topic: test_partitions_41       Partition: 2    Leader: none    Replicas: 2,3,4,1       Isr:
        Topic: test_partitions_41       Partition: 3    Leader: none    Replicas: 3,4,1,2       Isr:
```

I ve been looking for the problem where it comes from, and I found that 2 brokers were down when I ve been sending messages to this Topic.

I found also that [poste](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Controller+Internals) which talk about `PartitionStateChange`, they said that Topic in newpartition's state doesn't have either Leader nor isr.

How should I resolve this problem without removing topic?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!

The problem comes from broker controller, to resolve this problem I ressigned a new controller by zookeeper, this is the command I've runned in zookeeper:

```
su - kafka -c 'zookeeper-shell localhost:2181 rmr /controller'
```

Comment: Note: Do not run this in production

Comment: OneCricketeer, I think it's ok with production envs too, because I saw this in the kafka [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#dynamicbrokerconfigs). it just trigger new controller election.